# Bootstrap, added arrow and everything is misplaced now

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I added those green arrow buttons on a side of each picture, and now I have issue with having all my thumbnail in one row (One line); I will put this 4 pictures in a Iterator to be repeated, how ever they will be all out of order. I think there i need to have those Green arrows in some sort of a table or something, but I am not sure... i anyone has any idea how I can clear this code and make it better so I can have those green arrow besides picture without causing any issues. http://jsfiddle.net/8E9aB/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the documentation states:

> The default Bootstrap grid system utilizes 12 columns
>
> For a simple two column layout, create a .row and add the appropriate number of .span* columns. As this is a 12-column grid, each .span* spans a number of those 12 columns, ***and should always add up to 12 for each row*** (or the number of columns in the parent).

Reference: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html

Your are using 4 x `span4` in one row - this causes the row to "overflow" such that the final container is placed on a new line. By adjusting the four `span4` classes to `span3` you will have room for all images in one row.

Comment: Thanks for the answer if I want to bring those arrows inside under the picture, one arrow on left side of picture one arrow on right, and middle the number, how do i do that?

Comment: i do this, but they are not in a same line now 
'<div class="span6" style="float: left">
     <li><a  herf=""><img src="bootstrap/img/up.png"><a></li></div>
     <li><p>12345</p></li>
     <div class="span6" style="float: right" ></li><a href="#"><img src="bootstrap/img/down.png" float="right"></a></li></li>
     </div>
     </div>'

Comment: That would be a new question. I suggest that you accept this one if my solution worked and ask a new question if you want help to your other questions :)

Comment: if you could look at this one that would be really appreciated http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12764588/float-doesnt-work

Comment: I have added an answer to that question now :)