# Problems with float - place divs side by side

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css-float

Hi,

I would like two have the two green arrows in the same level. Right now the right arrow appears lower than the left arrow; I am using (inline floating):

```
<div class="span6" style="float: right; " >
```

I also would like to have the text `12345` right in the center of the two arrows.

Here is the code: http://jsfiddle.net/8E9aB/2/ - I am using bootstrap css.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possible duplicate of: [CSS: Placing divs left/center/right inside header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11570107/css-placing-divs-left-center-right-inside-header?lq=1)

I have updated your jsFiddle with a possible solution: http://jsfiddle.net/8E9aB/3/

My answer is based on: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11570931/700926 which explains the solution quite well.

-- UPDATE

As you are using twitter bootstrap, another solution could have been using the build-in grid system to accomplish more or less the same thing - take a look at it here: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#gridSystem

Comment: Your solution is perfect, but Unfortunately when I do the same thing, it doesnt work on my local computer and files . I do use Bootstrap

Comment: Well, as the solution seems to work in the context given by your jsFiddle I think it would be fair if you at least accepts or upvotes my answer. I cannot help you with your current problem as its kinda impossible to replicate without its context ;) However, I would suggest that you by process of elimination boils down the amount of code on your local machine until you figure out what might interfere with the provided solution - cause apparently, it sounds like you have some code that interferes with the given solution.

Comment: Here is a link to the grid bootstrap page: http://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/